# permanently disable bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

I simply don't use bluetooth. Since it can be a security risk and also drains the battery I would like to keep it deactivated. I quickly found the option to turn it off in the settings menu, but the problem is: it doesn't stay dead!

Everytime I pull my Nexus 4 out of standby mode bluetooth reappears in the top bar as if I never deactivated it.

How can I deactivate it so it stays deactivated or better yet how can I remove it from my phone entirely? 
I tried `sudo apt-get remove bluez bluetooth`, but I am not allowed to edit this package.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by disabling the upstart jobs for **bluetooth** and **bluetooth-touch**:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/bluetooth.override
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/bluetooth-touch.override
```

The **bluetooth** job controls BlueZ, which is the daemon used to establish bluetooth connections, and the **bluetooth-touch** job controls the programs that enable the bluetooth device on bootup on the phone, based on the model of the device.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work:

tee: /etc/init/bluetooth.override: the filesystem is only readable

Comment: @NotABluetoothUser: You could try to run `sudo mount / -o remount,rw` before running the suggested commands. This should make your filesystem writeable. I am not sure if this the best way of achieving that, but in my case it works without problems.

Comment: can't you just run those commands as sudo <command>? not sure if did the job, but I got no errors.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this possible is to make `/etc/rc.local` **a symbolic link** to `/etc/writable/rc.local`.
[Bug #1261091](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1261091) has been submitted to hopefully make this happen.